# Div with max-height containing another div with max-height (Overflow not working)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using `Materializecss` to display a modal. In my modal I have a `div Content` displaying items using `ng-repeat`. The problem is, as the content is filled, then the css-rule of my `content-div` never gets picked up. The overflow (scrollbar) occurs on my modal instead of my `content-div`.

I actually want my title and buttons to be visible at all times.

the (simplified html):

```
<div class="modal">
     <div class="title"> ... </div>
     <div class="content">
        <ul>
             <li class="collection-item" ng-repeat="usr in returnedUsers">{{usr.UserName}}</li>
         </ul>
     <div class="button">
</div>
```

css-classes

```
.modal {
background-clip: padding-box;
background-color: #eee;
border-radius: 2px;
display: none;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
max-height: 70%;
max-width: 55%;
overflow-y: auto;
padding: 24px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
transform: translate(0px);
z-index: 1000;

.content{
     max-height: 60%;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

simplified JSFiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uecef3mc/)

following SO-Post didn't solve the problem for me:

[css max-height inside max-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198246/css-max-height-inside-max-height)

[Table inside a div with max-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122991/table-inside-a-div-with-max-height)

[firefox css max-width and max-height inside max-height div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537665/firefox-css-max-width-and-max-height-inside-max-height-div)

**Note:** If possible i would like to prevent changes to the class `modal`

**Note2:** Setting height on my `.content`didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

you need to give a fixed value in `max-height` to your `.content ul` instead of `percentage`

> Generally, the content of a block box is confined to the content edges
>   of the box. In certain cases, a box may overflow, meaning its content
>   lies partly or entirely outside of the box, e.g.:
>
> - An element's height exceeds an explicit height assigned to the
>     containing block (i.e., the containing block's height is determined by
>     the 'height' property, not by content height).

Read more about [overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping)

```css
    .modal {
      background-clip: padding-box;
      background-color: #eee;
      border-radius: 2px;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      max-height: 70%;
      max-width: 55%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      padding: 24px;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      transform: translate(0px);
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    .content ul {
      max-height: 70px; /* whatever you want*/
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="title">MyTitle</div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="button">Btn1 - Btn2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: there is no way to maintain a percentage?